# generic timer high-order function in OCaml

Tags: generics, ocaml

I am trying to implement a generic timer function in OCaml which will take as input a function of arbitrary arity and return type ***'r*** and returns a function with:

- the same arity and types of input parameters
  , and
- return type `float * 'r` where the float would be a metric of the time spent in the function (e.g. reported by `Sys.time()`)

The problem is I can't implement it in such a way that it can handle functions of any arity. E.g. the following code:

```
let timer f =              
   let timerf x y =                                 
      let t0 = Sys.time ()                                         
      in let result = f x y                                                 
      in let diff = Sys.time() -. t0                                     
      in diff, result                                    
   in timerf
```

works only with functions of input arity 2. It is not obvious to me how to generalize it to handle functions of any arity. I was hoping the partial function applications would somehow magically solve the conundrum but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand your intention of making a timer function with arbitrary arity. But you cannot do it in an easy way in OCaml.

Moreover, a timer function with only one param is enough for use in practice:

```
let timer f x =
   let t0 = Sys.time()                                         
   in let result = f x                                              
   in let diff = Sys.time() -. t0                                     
   in diff, result
```

Since any function `g` with any arity can be passed to `timer` easily by:

```
let diff, result = timer (fun () -> g x1 x2 x3 ... xN) ()
```

*or better by using partial application (as suggested by @Andreas):*

```
let diff, result = timer (g x1 x2 x3 ... xN-1) xN
```

Comment: If you know that the function doesn't do anything interesting when partially applied (like most functions) then you don't even need the abstraction. It is sufficient to call `timer (g x1 x2 ... xN-1) xN`.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thanks, I incorporated your point into my answer.

Answer (score 7):

A remark on pad's solution that was too verbose to fit a comment.

In practice I found it was a better design to enforce `f : unit -> 'a` by passing `()` instead of a delayed argument.

```
let timer f =
  let t0 = Sys.time() in
  let result = f () in
  let t1 = Sys.time() in
  t1 -. t0, result
```

The reason why is that I tend to use the following pattern quite often:

```
let fun_to_test = match some_configuration with ... in
timer fun_to_test
```

pad's design, which is more appealing at first because more general, encourages you to instead write:

```
let fun_to_test, arg = match some_configuration with .... in
timer fun_to_test arg
```

The problem with this choice is that it seems fine at first, and after adding a few options you encounter a case where the arguments to the different functions to test are not of the same type. And you have a type error. Example of *wrong* code:

```
let fun_to_test, arg =
  if Random.bool ()
  then (foo, 3)
  else (bar, 3.2)
in timer fun_to_test arg
```

By forcing a closure with parameters pre-passed, I get "an existential type" for free here: the type of the last function argument does not appear in the type of `timer` application. I found this to be better in practice.

Of course, you can also delay the full call and use `()` as argument in pad's design. But I prefer a choice that forces me to do this, because otherwise I'm too tempted not to do it, and I pay it later.